# 'super' object has no attribute '_Parent__method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclass

I've read all the similar posts regarding this topic but none that I found related to my problem in a way that helped me figure out what was happening.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value
        self.__conn = httpsconnection # Specifics don't matter

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, id, type, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.data = self.__create_sub_class(id, type)

    def __create_sub_class(self, id, type):
        self.__conn.request(...)
        ...
        return data

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, id, value):
        super().__init__(id, externalVariable, value)
```

The error I am getting is `AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '_B__conn'`

Shouldn't class `C` inherit the variable from `B` which inherited it from `A`?

Comment: Why are you using double-underscore names? Those are explicitly designed to avoid inheritability.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: @MartijnPieters They're my private variables. A habit I picked up in another language when I was learning to program.

Comment: @Spedwards: there is no privacy model in Python, other than class-private names, and your use cases doesn't fit their goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use leading double-underscore names if you want to use those names in subclasses. The `__name` is explicitly designed to make the name *class private*, that is, only useful for the exact class. The idea is that you can use such names in a framework without then limiting what names subclasses can use.

Such names are *mangled* at compile time; they have `_ClassName` prefixed (with the current class name). Simply use single underscore names if you want to signal that a name is internal (Python has no actual privacy model, names are always accessible):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._conn = httpsconnection # Specifics don't matter

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, id, type, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.data = self._create_sub_class(id, type)

    def _create_sub_class(self, id, type):
        self._conn.request(...)
        ...
        return data
```

See [*Reserved classes of identifiers*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) in the lexical analysis documentation:

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes.

and the referenced [documentation on names](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named Ham will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the whole name-mangling. I don't know why but I've always preferred using double underscores over single. I guess that'll have to change now.